# DPDK forward received packets to default network stack

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, arp, dpdk

We're using DPDK (version 20.08 on ubuntu 20.04, c++ application) to receive UDP packets with a high throughput (>2 Mpps). We use a Mellanox ConnectX-5 NIC (and a Mellanox ConnectX-3 in an older system, would be great if the solution worked there aswell).

Contrary, since we only need to send a few configuration messages, we send messages through the default network stack. This way, we can use lots of readily available tools to send configuration messages; however, since all the received data is consumed by DPDK, these tools do not get back any messages.

The most prominent issue arises with ARP negotiation: the host tries to resolve addresses, the clients also do respond properly, however, these responses are all consumed by DPDK such that the host cannot resolve the addresses and refuses to send the actual UDP packets.

Our idea would be to **filter out the high throughput packets on our application and somehow "forward" everything else (e.g. ARP responses) to the default network stack. Does DPDK have a built-in solution for that?** I unfortunatelly coulnd't find anything in the examples.

I've recently heard about the [packet](https://linux.die.net/man/7/packet) function which allows to inject packets into SOCK_DGRAM sockets which may be a possible solution. I also couldn't find a sample implementation for our use-case, though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have shared the answer for the query. Please share some details on the NIC which will help me update the answer with the possibility using RTE_FLOW. Since it is mentioned as `since all the received data is consumed by DPDK` I have updated as generic one. Take a look at the same and let me know `if you need live debug. Please note not all NIC support all packet type.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! I've updated the question to include NIC specifications. It'd be great if the solution would also work on our older system using a Mellanox ConnectX-3; minimum requirement is a solution for the ConnectX-5.

Comment: @Dominic this is the precise reason why I requested the NIC in use. Because not all vendors and within vendors various NIC supports the FLOW director. hence the safest bet is to use SW bifurcation rather than relying on HW to bifurcate VF or PF. Also in case of ARP and Neighbour discovery it will be broadcasted to both PF and VF defeating your purpose to steer ARP to Kernel Network stack using HW assist. Please recheck the solution with HW Flow bifurcation.. Happy to explain or debug more for the right solution.

Comment: @Dominic are you clear why HW flow might not work for you? Do you need to sync up?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I unfortunately did not have the time yet to implement your suggestions since I'm busy with a different part of the project. I'll get back to you. We've created an issue in our internal gitlab repo, so we won't forget.  I personally tend towards using a software solution to be more portable and not rely on hw-specific features

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if the NIC in question supports the **embedded switch** feature, it should be possible to intercept the packets of interest in the hardware and redirect them to a virtual function (VF) associated with the physical function (PF), with the PF itself receiving everything else.

- The user configures SR-IOV feature on the NIC / host as well as virtualisation support;
- For a given NIC PF, the user adds a VF and binds it to the corresponding Linux driver;
- The DPDK application is run with the PF ethdev and a **representor** ethdev for the VF;
- To handle the packets in question, the application adds the corresponding flow rules.

The PF (ethdev `0`) and the VF representor (ethdev `1`) have to be explicitly specified by the corresponding EAL argument in the application: `-a [pci:dbdf],representor=vf0`.

As for the flow rules, there should be a pair of such.

The *first* rule's components are as follows:

- Attribute [`transfer`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html#attribute-transfer) (demands that matching packets be handled in the embedded switch);
- Pattern item [`REPRESENTED_PORT`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html#item-represented-port) with `port_id = 0` (instructs the NIC to intercept packets coming *to* the embedded switch *from* the network port *represented by* the PF ethdev);
- Pattern items [matching on network headers](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html#data-matching-item-types) (these provide narrower match criteria);
- Action [`REPRESENTED_PORT`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html#action-represented-port) with `port_id = 1` (redirects packets to the VF).

In the *second* rule, item `REPRESENTED_PORT` has `port_id = 1`, and action `REPRESENTED_PORT` has `port_id = 0` (that is, this rule is inverse). Everything else should remain the same.

It is important to note that some drivers do not support *item* `REPRESENTED_PORT` at the moment. Instead, they  expect that the rules be added via the corresponding ethdevs. This way, for the provided example: the first rule goes to ethdev `0`, the second one goes to ethdev `1`.

---

As per the OP update, the adapter in question might indeed support the embedded switch feature. However, as noted above, *item* `REPRESENTED_PORT` might not be supported. The rules should be inserted via specific ethdevs. Also, one more attribute, [`ingress`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html#attribute-traffic-direction), might need to be specified.

In order to check whether this scheme works, one should be able to deploy a VF (as described above) and run [`testpmd`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/) with the aforementioned EAL argument. In the command line of the application, the two flow rules can be tested as follows:

- `flow create 0 ingress transfer pattern eth type is 0x0806 / end actions represented_port ethdev_port_id 1 / end`
- `flow create 1 ingress transfer pattern eth type is 0x0806 / end actions represented_port ethdev_port_id 0 / end`

Once done, that should pass ARP packets to the VF (thus, to the network interface) in question. The rest of packets should be seen by `testpmd` in active forwarding mode (`start` command).

NOTE: it is recommended to switch to the most recent DPDK release.

Answer (score 0):

For the current use case, the best option is to make use of DPDK TAP PMD (which is part of LINUX DPDK). You can use Software or Hardware to filter the specific packets then sent it desired TAP interface.

A simple example to demonstrate the same would be making use DPDK `skeleton` example.

1. build the DPDK example via `cd [root folder]/example/skeleton; make static`
2. pass the desired Physical DPDK PMD NIC using DPDK eal options `./build/basicfwd -l 1 -w [pcie id of DPDK NIC] --vdev=net_tap0;iface=dpdkTap`
3. In second terminal execute `ifconfig dpdkTap 0.0.0.0 promisc up`
4. Use tpcudmp to capture Ingress and Egress packets using `tcpdump -eni dpdkTap -Q in` and `tcpdump -enu dpdkTap -Q out` respectively.

Note: you can configure ip address, setup TC on `dpdkTap`. Also you can run your custom socket programs too. You do not need to invest time on TLDP, ANS, VPP as per your requirement you just need an mechanism to inject and receive packet from Kernel network stack.

Answer (score 0):

We've implemented a solution based on flow isolation using the bifurcated driver (which is default for our devices using mlx5).

In this example, we're filtering all the UDP packets to be handled by DPDK and leave all the others to the kernel network stack. This pattern can be easily extended to fit different packets.

Handling of API calls return values (mostly error nums) is ommited in this example but is strongly encouraged in real applications.

```cpp
/* These would mostly be set from a function call */
const uint16_t rx_rings = 1, tx_rings = 1;
uint16_t nb_rxd = 1000;
uint16_t nb_txd = 1000;
uint16_t q;
struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;
struct rte_eth_txconf txconf;

if(!rte_eth_dev_is_valid_port(port))
    return -1;

rte_eth_dev_info_get(port, &dev_info);

/* Setup flow rules. */

/* Flow items */
struct rte_flow_item flow_pattern[4]; /* 4 parts: ethernet, ipv4, udp, end */

/* Ethernet Layer */
static struct rte_flow_item eth_item = {RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH, 0, 0, 0};
flow_pattern[0] = eth_item;

/* IPv4 Layer */
struct rte_flow_item ipv4_item;
ipv4_item.type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
flow_pattern[1] = ipv4_item;

/* UDP Layer */
struct rte_flow_item udp_item;
udp_item.type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_UDP;
flow_pattern[2] = udp_item;

/* Terminate the pattern list */
static struct rte_flow_item end_item = {RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END, 0, 0, 0};
flow_pattern[3] = end_item;

/* Flow actions */
struct rte_flow_action flow_actions[2];
static struct rte_flow_action_queue flow_action_queue_conf = {0}; // enqueue in queue 0
static struct rte_flow_action flow_action_queue
{
    RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE, &flow_action_queue_conf
};
flow_actions[0] = flow_action_queue;

/* Terminate flow action list */
static struct rte_flow_action flow_action_end = {RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END, 0};
flow_actions[1] = flow_action_end;

/* Flow attributes */
static struct rte_flow_attr flow_attrs;
flow_attrs.ingress = 1;

/* Initialize flow isolation to forward messages to kernel network stack */
/* This will only work with bifurcated drivers */
struct rte_flow_error flow_errors;
rte_flow_isolate(port, 1, &flow_errors);

/* Configure the Ethernet device. */
rte_eth_dev_configure(port, rx_rings, tx_rings, &port_conf);

/* Allocate and set up 1 RX queue per Ethernet port. */
for(q = 0; q < rx_rings; q++)
{
    rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_rxd, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL, mbuf_pool);
}

/* Allocate and set up 1 TX queue per Ethernet port. */
for(q = 0; q < tx_rings; q++)
{
    rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port, q, nb_txd, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), &txconf);
}

/* Validate flow */
/* This only works after configuring the port to forward to */
rte_flow_validate(port, &flow_attrs, flow_pattern, flow_actions, &flow_errors);

/* Start the Ethernet port. */
rte_eth_dev_start(port);

/* Create the flow /*
/* This will only work after the queue was started */
rte_flow_create(port, &flow_attrs, flow_pattern, flow_actions, &flow_errors);
```